# Action required to do the operation "browse"

Tags: c#, winforms

If i created a button named Browse ,,If i click Browse button i have to
browse my system folders .Can any one give me the required code to browse
the specific folders

Comment: I removed the "optimized" because this has nothing to do with any optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) if you are wanting to find a folder.
If you are wanting to open a file, you can use the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx).

Both links provide examples of how to use the dialogs.

[This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) provides how to get the special system folders. And you can specify the type of special folder you want by using the appropriate enumeration.  Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) for those.

Essentially, you are going to do something like so if you want to pop up a dialog and browse to the System folder and select some files from there:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
    od.InitialDirectory = Environgment.SpecialFolder.System;
    od.Multiselect = true;
    if (od.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       // do stuff
       // od.Filenames will hold the string[] of selected files
    }
}
```

Comment: What is 'Environgment' here which namespace required for this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display the results in a list named files something like:

```
String directory = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
String[]files = Directory.GetFiles (directory);
foreach (String file in files)
  files.Add (file);
```

You can use a FolderBrowserDialog control and call the code there if you want to browse multiple directories.